# Efficiently Calculate Accuracy of NN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

The current way I'm calculating accuracy is very inefficient. This is because I'm looking at the entire dataset together whereas in my forward propagation I broke it down into batches.

**How would I test accuracy efficiently in a separate function?** One way is to break up the test data into batches and run the model on each batch, then concatenate all batches and test against the true labels. Is there a quicker way? Also **is the way I'm using the model to make predictions on a different dataset the most efficient way to do so or should I be also breaking that down into batches?**

Ideally, I would like to have this separately in a method so that I can call accuracy for train, test and dev datasets.

This is the part of my code that is running the model:

```
cost = compute_cost(fc_layer_4, yph)
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    mini_batches = random_batches(X,Y)
    num_batches = len(mini_batches)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_cost = 0
        for batch, (x_mini, y_mini) in enumerate(mini_batches,1):
            _,c = sess.run([optimiser, cost], feed_dict={xph:x_mini, yph:y_mini})
            epoch_cost += c/num_batches
            print("epoch: ",epoch+1," / ", num_epochs,"... batch: ", batch)

        costs.append(epoch_cost)

    plt.plot(costs)

    W1,b1,W2,b2 = sess.run([W1,b1,W2,b2])

return W1,b1,W2,b2
```

I would then like to store the prediction to return it later and use it to calculate the accuracy. I would also then use a method similar to the following to make predictions on different datasets:

```
def predict(X,parameters):
    W1,b1,W2,b2 = parameters    
    conv_1 = convolution(X,W1)
    activation_1= tf.nn.relu(conv_1)
    pool_1 = max_pooling_2_x_2(activation_1)

    conv_2 = convolution(pool_1,W2)
    activation_2 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2)
    pool_2 = max_pooling_2_x_2(activation_2)

    flattened_3 = flatten_layer(pool_2)
    flattened_3 = tf.nn.relu(flattened_3)

    fc_layer_3 = fully_connected_layer(flattened_3,1024)
    fc_layer_4 = fully_connected_layer(fc_layer_3,10)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        prediction = sess.run(fc_layer_4, feed_dict={xph:X})

    return prediction
```

Comment: Why do you think evaluating accuracy per batch is more efficient than evaluating it on all samples at once?

Comment: My computer is old and crashes if I run it on all samples at once. Any ideas on writing a separate function for accuracy?

Comment: Also, what if I have hundreds of thousands of records in a test set. What is the conventional way of testing for accuracy?

Comment: Usually you create batches as large as fits the GPU memory. From the efficiency point of view it does not make any difference if you pass them through one by one or all at once.

Comment: You can also write an algorithm to extract at random a (smaller) subset, which you can use for performance assessment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

After taking the comments into consideration, I got it sorted out. My answer is the content of another question I've asked which can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346083/nn-accuracy-and-understanding-tensorflow-graphs):